# How in C # we can focus on a text box?

Tags: c#

In C #, I defined a class called ( Utility ) in which I defined a set of functions that I can use inside the program.

I defined an email template check function that's apparently grammatically fine. If I use the extension ( .com ) in the program, it is not a problem, but we get into trouble when we use an extension other than ( .com ). In this case, it is not possible to leave our control box. Can you help me figure out what the problem is?

```
private static string[] formatEmail = new string[4];

public static void CheckFormatEmail(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox, 
System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider errorProvider)
    {
        formatEmail[0] = ".com";
        formatEmail[1] = ".org";
        formatEmail[2] = ".ir";
        formatEmail[3] = ".net";

        int indexChar = 0;
        int lenght = 0;
        string subString = null;
        string suffix = null;

        if ((textBox.Text).Contains("@"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < formatEmail.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!textBox.Text.EndsWith(formatEmail[i]))
                {
                    textBox.Focus();
                    textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(252, 91, 91);
                    errorProvider.SetError(textBox, "وارد كنيد" + "** Username@domain.com **" + "لطفا ايميل را در قالب");
                }
                else
                {
                    suffix = formatEmail[i];
                    indexChar = textBox.Text.LastIndexOf('@');

                    if (string.Compare(suffix, ".ir") == 0)
                    {
                        lenght = (textBox.Text.Length - indexChar) - 3;

                        subString = textBox.Text.Substring(indexChar, lenght);

                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subString.Remove(0, 1)))
                        {
                            textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
                            errorProvider.Clear();
                            ;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(252, 91, 91);
                            errorProvider.SetError(textBox, "وارد كنيد" + "** Username@domain.com **" + "لطفا ايميل را در قالب");
                            textBox.Focus();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lenght = (textBox.Text.Length - indexChar) - 4;

                        subString = textBox.Text.Substring(indexChar, lenght);

                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subString.Remove(0, 1)))
                        {
                            textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
                            errorProvider.Clear();
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(252, 91, 91);
                            errorProvider.SetError(textBox, "وارد كنيد" + "** Username@domain.com **" + "لطفا ايميل را در قالب");
                            textBox.Focus();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }               
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.Focus();
            textBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(252, 91, 91);
            errorProvider.SetError(textBox, "وارد كنيد" + "** Username@domain.com **" + "لطفا ايميل را در قالب");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is it because of `textBox.Focus();`?

Comment: Your e-mail address validation logic is incorrect (not to mention _very restrictive_: your logic doesn't accept any ccTLDs and most TLDs (why?)) so right now your programs thinks that my perfectly valid e-mail address is invalid. Anyway _don't reinvent the wheel_, to validate e-mail addresses in .NET all you need is `(new EmailAddressAttribute).IsValid("validemail@example.de")` - and to extract the host and user components use `new MailAddress( "validemail@example.de" ).Host` or `.User` (but only after validating it to prevent an exception).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to fix your code, I'll say that you're *doing it wrong* at a fundamental level by reimplementing your own e-mail address validation logic - which is already a solved problem with countless of solutions.

So don't reinvent the wheel, just do this:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class MyValidationMethods
{
    public static void ValidateEmailAddressTextBox( TextBox textBox, ErrorProvider err, Boolean focusOnError )
    {
        if( textBox is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(textBox));
        if( err is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(err));

        //

        if( TryValidateEmailAddress( textBox.Text, out MailAddress? addr ) )
        {
            err.SetError( textBox, "" ); // Don't use `Clear()` for a single control, instead use `SetError()` with an empty message.

            String dnsHostName = addr.Host;
            String[] dnsLabels = dnsHostName.Split('.');
            // TODO: If you really want to filter or restrict e-mail DNS names then you can do that here by doing case-insensitive matches on the last 2 or 3 elements in `dnsLabels`.
        }
        else
        {
            err.SetError( textBox, "\"${textBox.Text}\" is not a valid e-mail address." );
            if( focusOnError ) textBox.Focus();
        }
    }

    // NOTE: If you're targeting .NET Core or later (e.g. .NET 5, .NET 6, etc) then be-aware that `EmailAddressAttribute` was changed to only perform very simplistic (almost useless!) validation instead of using its previously stricter regex.
    // * See:
    //      * https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/4319
    //      * https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/20884
    // * However this code below (in `TryValidateEmailAddress`) still okay on .NET 5+ because the `MailAddress` constructor still performs its own (unchanged) validation and will throw an exception (which is instantly caught).
    //     * Though it *does* accept e-mail address strings with a display-name component, e.g. `"Something" <username@host>"`.
    //     * If you want to disallow that then a quick-fix is to reject the string if it contains double-quotes. This is included in the code below within the `#if NET5_0_OR_GREATER` code.
    //        * There are limited scenarios where double-quotes are valid in an RFC email-address without a display-name, but they're esoteric and not worth handling, imo.

    private static readonly EmailAddressAttribute _validator = new EmailAddressAttribute();

    private static Boolean TryValidateEmailAddress( String inputEmailAddress, [NotNullWhen(true)] out MailAddress? addr )
    {
        
#if NET5_0_OR_GREATER
        if( _validator.IsValid( inputEmailAddress ) && !inputEmailAddress.Contains('"') )
#else
        if( _validator.IsValid( inputEmailAddress ) )
#endif
        {
            try
            {
                addr = new MailAddress( inputEmailAddress  );
                return true;
            }
            catch( Exception ex ) when ( ex is ArgumentException || ex is FormatException )
            {
            }
        }

        addr = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I made the `.Focus()` call conditional via the `Boolean focusOnError` method parameter so you can validate multiple controls at-once without needing to `.Focus()` on a single specific control.

For as usage example, I assume you have a method to validate all controls-at-once (`ValidateEverything` below), in addition to a [Control.Validating`event-handler][1] named`EmailAddressTextBox_Validating`, and that your` ErrorProvider`control is named`formErrors`) and represents errors for multiple controls instead of just 1.

```cs
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private TextBox       firstEmailInputTextBox;
    private TextBox       anotherEmailInputTextBox;
    private ErrorProvider formErrors;

    // [...]

    // Uses `focusOnError: true`:
    private void EmailAddressTextBox_Validating( Object sender, CancelEventArgs e )
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;

        MyValidationMethods.ValidateEmailAddressTextBox( tb, this.formErrors, focusOnError: true );
    }

    // Uses `focusOnError: false` to avoid breaking the UX:
    private void ValidateEverything()
    {
        MyValidationMethods.ValidateEmailAddressTextBox( this.firstEmailInputTextBox, this.formErrors, focusOnError: false );

        MyValidationMethods.ValidateEmailAddressTextBox( this.anotherEmailInputTextBox, this.formErrors, focusOnError: false);
    }
}
```

As for why you're having issues with `.Focus()`, it's because you're inconsistently mixing `break` and `return` inconsistently - but if you simplify your logic (as done in my answer) it removes the problem entirely.

Comment: For what is worth, the current (net core/5/6) implementation of `EmailAddressAttribute` validation is EXTREMELY lacking. This is because at some point on the transition from NET Framework to NET Core they decided (because of a security bulletin) Regex couldn't be used for validation on component model attributes. I'd not use that validation and I'd (in this case) reinvent the wheel. Agreed, not like the OP, but not like the current implementation of this validation

Comment: For the interested, [here's the code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs), which basically only checks that there's just one '@' in the string and it's not the first nor the last character, **and that's all it does**

Comment: And by the way, the .NET Framework one ([code here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs)) before the Regex trimming from attributes was not that great, either

Comment: @Jcl Oh wow, thanks for the tip - I suppose as a last-resort we can use `new MailAddress` in a `try/catch` - unless there's something better?

Comment: I don't think `MailAddress` validates at all: its purpose is basically encoding the data in SMTP related format, not validating. I don't think there's any good validation of an email address built-in the framework now. I basically reinvent the wheel for this one (or use FluentValidator, which has two modes, one compatible with the .NET validator, and its own regex based one: more info [on their docs](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html#email-validator))

Comment: Btw, there's also [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/91da4ac9fd3470fe4798f0151e36f1769a9e9c2c/src/libraries/System.Net.Mail/src/System/Net/Mail/MailAddressParser.cs) but it's `internal`: it's a non-regex parser that should be RFC compliant... but again, it's internal and not intended for public usage

Comment: @Jcl `MailAddress`'s ctor uses `internal static class MailAddressParser` ( [ref-source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailAddressParser.cs,477772feab0a443e) ) - it's present in (at-least) .NET 4.8 and .NET 6 (I only checked those 2, though in the .NET 6 version `MailAddressParser` was refactored around the `TryParse` convention instead of throwing).

Comment: yeah, it looks like it does, my bad... I knew about `MailAddressParser` (I referended it on the last comment) but didn't know `MailAddress` used it. Then yes, maybe a `try/catch` and a `new MailAddress` could be a solution for not reinventing the wheel. Not a specially good one (I'd rather have the `MailAddressParser` public and use `TryParse`), but one has to get what is offerred

Comment: @Jcl Hey, if we could unilaterally make sweeping design changes to .NET then I'd not only make `MailAddressParser` public, but I'd also nuke the `Convert` class, make 
`IList<T>` extend `IReadOnlyList<T>` (it still doesn't!), and make `String.Format` an extension-method to `String`. _Oh, if only..._

Comment: I'm reading the `MailAddress` source diagonally, and I think it accepts "display names" in the `address` constructor parameters (i.e.: `"Something" <username@host>` would be a valid email address), which is more likely not what you want. Seems the `displayName` constructor parameter is for overriding the display name you may pass in `address`, not for *necessarily* constructing it. That could be a no-no in some cases, and needs to be taken into account. I'd rather just keep using a simple regex-based validator :-)

Comment: @Jcl In my use-cases, that's fine, e.g. when passing raw SMTP header values (e.g. `To:`) directly to `MailAddress`, as those do contain display-names.

Comment: My *current* use case for email validation is a bit different and I don't care about actually "sending" emails, but rather gathering them (for other checks: it's a cyber security platform so I can't discuss a lot from it), and I need to know they are valid *internet* email addresses (not necessarily RFC: my hosts can't be TLDs or allow many other things which "SMTP email" allows but "internet email" doesn't). I think I'll keep using my regex for the time being :-)

Comment: @Jcl I've updated my code in this answer with advice for .NET 5+ users. Thanks again for the tip.